# Tor in virtual machine - 502 bad gateway

Tags: virtual-machine, privacy, tor

I'm trying to run Tor in virtual machine. It used to work, but now when I try to access sites I get "502 bad gateway" error from Privoxy instead of requested site. I tried fixing time to correct one  with date command but I still get 502 error. I use Virtualbox, Linux guest, and Tor+Privoxy setup.

Comment: What's in tor's log file?

Comment: "Application request when we're believed to be offline. Optimistically trying directory fetches again." and then, 2 minutes later: "Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to scrubbed:80. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)"

Comment: It seems your Privoxy configuration isn´t properly configured

Answer (score 1):

Check the virtual machine can access the internet by pinging then using wget/curl to get a webpage, since the log suggests that is where the error is.  If you can't then it's a networking problem with the virtual machine and you'll need to make sure the Virtualbox network is correctly configured and that the virtual machine is getting an ip address correctly.

If the virtual machine can connect then it's likely a config issue with Tor or Privoxy.  Try bypassing Privoxy by using Tor directly on the virtual machine - `torify wget http://www.google.com` should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Google normally without Tor.

If you can do this, it is possible that your ISP is blocking TOR or the page you are visiting is just filtered at the other end.

Also, if you can visit Google normally, it means that this problem is related to Tor itself and nothing to do with being inside a virtual machine.

Comment: I used to have this problem when I had old date and time in my virtual machine, but I always fixed it by setting actual time with date command. Now it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I can visit Google normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are being blocked from establishing a connection with the Tor network try using a bridge. Basically bridges are secret lists of Tor servers and since they are released only a few at a time not all of them can be blocked. [See here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges).

Is it possible to try using Tor on the host machine, or on an entirley different machine using the same network connection? If this succeeds it would rule out any posibility of your network blocking Tor.